# .NET Core Entity Framework Remove explicitly created Join tables/configuration for M:M

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Listing and a Skills table which have a M:M relationship between them. At the moment I explicitly created a Join table called ListingSkill.

My relationship looks like this:

```cs
public class Listing : EntityBase {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    
    public ICollection<ListingSkill> ListingSkills { get; set; }
    
}



public class Skill : EntityBase {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<ListingSkill> ListingSkills { get; set; }
}


public class ListingSkill : EntityBase {
    
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
    
}
```

My DB Context looks like this:

```cs
builder.Entity<ListingSkill>().HasKey(ls => new { ls.ListingId, ls.SkillId });

builder.Entity<ListingSkill>()
  .HasOne(l => l.Listing)
  .WithMany(ls => ls.ListingSkills)
  .HasForeignKey(s => s.ListingId);

builder.Entity<ListingSkill>()
   .HasOne(u => u.Skill)
   .WithMany(lw => lw.ListingSkills)
   .HasForeignKey(l => l.SkillId);
```

My skills table is pre-seeded with values, when I create a Listing entity, I pass in the list of skill ids I would like to associate with that Listing, and then the join table also gets populated with the entries of the Listing Id and all the skill Ids.

This works for me, but I would like a simpler way of handling this. I don't want to be handling the creating of the relationships this way since it gets quite confusing with more M:M relationships in my program.

In my service layer I do something like this, and then save the Listing entity, which populates the Join table appropriately.

```cs
listing.ListingSkills = skillIds
  .Select(id => new ListingSkill() { SkillId = id, ListingId = listing.Id})
.ToList();
```

Can someone please assist on a cleaner way to accomplish the same goal without doing all of this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please assist on a cleaner way to accomplish the same goal
> without doing all of this?

Well, you don't need to manage them explicitly because entity framework has its own mechanism to do it.

So you can use shadow properties within your `Listing` class and should include `ICollection<Skill>`  into it.

Considerting your exsiting code and scenario, you can do that in following way:

```
public class Listing : EntityBase {
    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Modify relationship in the DB context:

Instead of your current entity defination, you can update that like below:

```
builder.Entity<Listing>()
    .HasMany(l => l.Skills)
    .WithMany(s => s.Listings)
    .UsingEntity<ListingSkill>(
        j => j.HasOne(ls => ls.Listing).WithMany(),
        j => j.HasOne(ls => ls.Skill).WithMany());
```

Once you can modify above configuration, now you can assign skill IDs directly to the Skills collection:

```
listing.Skills = skillIds.Select(id => new Skill { Id = id }).ToList();
```

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#examples) for additional implementational assistance.